# Why is me Set working as an array list in Java programming?

Tags: java, set

Hello again fellow programmers.

so I'm creating a program that allows users to specify the type of insurance cover they want as part of an insurance policy.

Since their is only 4 types of cover to choose from I want to use a set or hash set to keep track of the types of cover offered to users.

The problem is that is does not seem to get rid of duplicates it is treating it like an arraylist and when I print out the contents of the set i get duplicates which should not happen in a set.

This is the code I used to pass the created insurance type objects  to the insurance policy class.After they have been instantiated.

```
CoverType theInsuranceType = new CoverType("Fire",250);
theInsurancePolicy.includeCover(theInsuranceType);
```

and this is the code I used in the insurance policy class to keep track of the type of insurance that a user has taken out.

```
    import java.util.*;
    // Class:   InsurancePolicy
    // Purpose: To represent a particular customer's insurance agreement
    public class InsurancePolicy {


            //ArrayList<Product> orderList = new ArrayList<Product>();
        private static int totalPolicyCost;

        private static String name = null;

        private static int price = 0;

        private int amount = 0;

        private static int total = 0, claims = 0;


        private static Set<CoverType> TheCoverType = new HashSet<CoverType>();


        public static boolean includeCover(CoverType which)
        {

            TheCoverType.add(which);
            System.out.println(which.getName()+" Has ben added to your insurance    policy");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("-----------------------");  
            return true;

        }
```

I have done this as part of the the insurance policy class to iterate over the set and pull out and print values of each object for the user and that is where im getting the duplicates.

```
    Iterator<CoverType> iter = TheCoverType.iterator();
        int cash =0;
        while (iter.hasNext())
        {
            CoverType type = iter.next();
             cash =  type.getPrice();
            amount = amount + cash;
            System.out.println("This one Cost.  "+ cash);
                        // int cost = TheCoverType.getPrice().next();
//          if theCover     


        }
        amount = amount+ 100;
        String message = "So all up total cost of the policy is. "+cash; 
        return amount;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wonder how many of us will come up with the same answer?

Comment: Most IDEs support generating hashCode and equals for your classes. (Saves you having to write it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type held by the set I assume is "CoverType", right? If so, do you overload equals and hashCode() for this class?

Comment: yes it is and why would i overload the  equals and hashCode()

Comment: @Binyomin: smart alec answer: so  you don't get the problem you're having. Better answer: because this is what HashSets use to identify a unique object and to thus remove duplicates.

Comment: I have done this as part of the the insurance policy class to iterate over the set to pull  out the info         Iterator<CoverType> iter = TheCoverType.iterator();
  int cash =0;
  while (iter.hasNext())
  {
   CoverType type = iter.next();
    cash =  type.getPrice();
   amount = amount + cash;
   System.out.println("This one Cost.  "+ cash);
//   int cost = TheCoverType.getPrice().next();
//   if theCover  
   
   
  }
  amount = amount+ 100;
  String message = "So all up total cost of the policy is. "+cash; 
  return amount;

Comment: ouch. please post your code as an edit to your original question as code is quite unreadable in comments.

Comment: @Binyomin: but i still don't see where you've implemented the recommendations all three of us have made, to give CoverType a decent equals and hashCode override. Shouldn't you start there since all three of us can't be wrong? Check Google to see how to do this well. StackOverflow has many decent examples.

Comment: thanks again I have just improved the layout for better clarity.

Answer (score 5):

Your objects that you want to put in a set need to implement [equals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [hashcode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).

Even if all fields are "equal", you won't get object equality (`.equals()`) in java unless you override those methods.

Answer (score 2):

Have you implemented .equals and .hashCode for your CoverType class?

Comment: no how why would i do that?? im new to using set (very new!!)

Comment: you would need to override the equals and hashcode method because those are the methods that would be used to find if an object is equal to another object and then to retrieve the object (HashSet internally uses HashMap so remember, hashing, buckets et-all)